# Changing the http protocol of web browser control

Tags: c#, winforms, http, webbrowser-control

I am getting HTTP 501/HTTP 505 
While if I using a webrequest I could change the http protocol version to 1.0 or 1.1. It seems to be impossible with web browser control or eztools-software.com/tools/wow/wow_net.asp

How can I change the http protocol version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Web Browser control does not expose a public method for changing the HTTP Protocol version used. You can disable HTTP/1.1 globally using the Internet Options > Advanced control panel, but this is not advised due to the performance impact of doing so.

You could integrate FiddlerCore into your application and use that to change the outbound request's HTTP version.

Having said that, I don't think that changing the protocol version is likely to impact your server's HTTP/501 or HTTP/505 response. Have you tried changing the protocol only using Fiddler to see if it matters?